# how to iterate and get the values for the class passed dynamically

Tags: java, generics

I have a method which accepts any class type object, i want to iterate the object and print the details.

```
void showDetails(List<?> obj) {
    System.out.println(obj);
     for(Object ob : obj) {
        //how to print the course and student details
    } 
}
```

How can i iterate and print the details of the obj values passed. Below is the complete sample code.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class Student{
    private int stid;
    public int getStid() {
        return stid;
    }

    public void setStid(int stid) {
        this.stid = stid;
    }

}
class Details extends Student{
    private String name;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    private String address;
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }


}

class Course extends Student{
    private String shortTerm;
    private String fullTerm;
    public String getShortTerm() {
        return shortTerm;
    }
    public void setShortTerm(String shortTerm) {
        this.shortTerm = shortTerm;
    }
    public String getFullTerm() {
        return fullTerm;
    }
    public void setFullTerm(String fullTerm) {
        this.fullTerm = fullTerm;
    }

}
public class Test {

    void showDetails(List<?> obj) {
        System.out.println(obj);
         for(Object ob : obj) {
            //how to print the course and student details
        } 
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Details d1 = new Details();
        d1.setName("John");
        d1.setAddress("Street 21");
        d1.setStid(10);
        Details d2 = new Details();
        d2.setName("Sam");
        d2.setAddress("Street 151");
        d2.setStid(11);
        List<Details> listObj = new ArrayList<>();
        listObj.add(d1);
        listObj.add(d2);

        new Test().showDetails(listObj);

        //course
        Course c1 = new Course();
        c1.setShortTerm("6months");
        c1.setFullTerm("12 months");
        c1.setStid(111);
        List<Course> courseList = new ArrayList<>();
        courseList.add(c1);
        new Test().showDetails(courseList);
    }
}
```

I want to make the `showDetails(List<?> obj)` as a generic method so that any class object can be passed which are subclasses of the Student class. `List<?>`, where `?` denotes any class object which are subclasses of Student class.

Comment: Do you want the list to only contain *one* type of student, or can it contain any number of different subclasses of student? The latter is satisfied by simply declaring it to be a `List<Student>`

Comment: I want the list to contain student or subclasses of the student. @JonK

Comment: That's not quite what I was asking, I perhaps didn't word my question particularly well... The input list needs to contain any type of student, but will any given list just contain *one* type of student, or will it contain a mixture of different types of student?

Comment: It may contain mixture of different types of Student. In showDetails method i should able to print all the values (name, address if i have passed the Details object) and the studentID(stid) of the object i have passed..

Comment: So in that case `showDetails(List<Student> obj)` would mean the method accepts a list containing only objects that have `Student` in their class hierarchy. Does your `showDetails` method need to print out *all* fields, or just those that the `Student` class knows about?

Comment: showDetails should print all the details as i said in the above comment..In showDetails method i should able to print all the values (name, address if i have passed the Details object) and the studentID(stid) of the object i have passed..

Comment: If you need to print out every single property of the objects then you're probably going to need to delve into reflection in order to implement it in a generic way. If you have a limited, known subset of subclasses then you could avoid it by using a set of `instanceof` checks and then casting to the appropriate type, although it's not a good solution

Comment: Maybe you want to do something like this List<? extends Student>

Comment: I tired that, but unable to get the details like name, address if i have passed the Details object when iterating using for loop.Can u give an example of  showDetails(..) when passed new Test().showDetails(listObj); in the sample code shown above.

Comment: I think user31601's answer will get you where you need, otherwise as JonK says you may have to dig in to reflection (I love reflection) -- but aside... `extends` in OO designates an `is-a` relationship, so _Details is-a Student_? _Course is-a Student_? Maybe re-thinking your object hierarchy would get you a better solution. e.g. a "Course" is a separate thing from a Student; a Course maybe contains a List<Student> for the students enrolled, but also a Student can have a List<Course> for the courses that student is taking.

Answer (score 0):

The standard polymorphic way way of doing this would be to have `Student` (and its subclasses) know how to turn its own details into a `String`. For instance, you could have somethign like this:

```
class Student{
    private int stid;

    public int getStid() {
        return stid;
    }

    public void setStid(int stid) {
        this.stid = stid;
    }

    public String getDetails() {
        return "ID: " + getStid();
    }

}

class Details extends Student {

    /*
     ... other fields etc...
     */

    @Override
    public String getDetails() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(super.getDetails()).append('\n');
        sb.append("Name: ").append(getName()).append('\n');
        // TODO: append other fields
        return sb.toString();
    }

}

class Course extends Student {

    /*
     ... other fields etc...
     */

    @Override
    public String getDetails() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        // TODO: similar to Details class
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Then your show details function can use the `getDetails()` method:

```
void showDetails(List<? extends Student> obj) {
    System.out.println(obj);
     for(Student s : obj) {
        System.out.println(s.getDetails());
    } 
}
```